# [Android ]How to handle Error when calling API apply for clean architecture?

Tags: android, architecture, clean-architecture

I am wonder for how to handle error if API response unexpected result.
Applying for clean architecture, I want to wrap the result into a seal class like this:

```
sealed class Result {
    data class <T> Success(data: T): Result()
    data class Fail(exception: Exception): Result
}
```

Activity will handle UI follow result type.
I am thinking about 2 ways to handle:

1. When calling API in viewModel, the exception will be handle at CoroutineExceptionHandler.
2. All the use case will return Result type. The error will be converted and wrap into Result from data layer into presentation layer.

Thanks for helping me! Peace.

Answer (score 2):

You could do the conversion in the Repository. It should be an intermediate layer between the HTTP client (Retrofit, for example) and your use cases. Your Repository receives as parameter the client and exposes functions to perform each request doing a try/catch to return your result class. Your use cases only interact with the Repository. Be careful to don't catch all the exceptions in the result class; only the ones that are expected from the API contract. It is better to get a crash to spot the error when something unexpected happens.